# Can you get the function equations just based on the graph ( without knowing whether it is linear,quadratic...)

Tags: calculus

For example,
I tell a kid draw a line(it doesn't have to be straight, anything you like) in the coordinate system. Am i able to find the equation for f(x)?
Also, if i have a program to which i give an input ( a number) and it gives me an output.Will i be able to find f(x) and how much data(how many input and output pairs) will i need ?

Comment: it's possible for the linear function but not for other types

Comment: but why?( how do you know)

Comment: this question is way too broadly phrased.

No generally not, in special cases (polynomials,...) yes

Comment: because there is exactly one line that goes thru two data points

Comment: i know how to find a linear equation, i am asking why cant you do it if you dont know the power of x

Comment: There is infinite number of ways to connect two points so it's impossible to guess a function without additional info. Interpolation can help you but  it's going to be an approximation.

Comment: @MilanStojanovic Show us the line and graph about which we are talking..

Comment: There are a lot of simple functions which have familiar graphs which you can guess but in general given any number of points you can make infinitely many functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that program which gives you 3 outputs to 3 input points, you can construct a polynomial of second degree matching this program. But there are infinitely many polynomials agreeing with that constructed polynomial on these 3 points whilst not agreeing on other ones.

Since you can do this for every number $n$ you will at least have to have countably many input-output-pairs.

I think there is a theorem telling you that if you have uncountably many input-output-pairs then there is just one polynomial which matches these pairs, but I'm not sure about that

Comment: how can i find that theorem

Comment: as already said I'm not sure!

Comment: if someone know it would be very helpful

Comment: if you know it's a polynomial of degree $n$, you need $n+1$ points do define a unique polynomial that goes thru those points. google method of successive differences or refer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685472/find-n-degree-polynomial-from-n1-points

Comment: This isn't the best way to approximate your function. Since the polynomial still may not converge to your function even if it agrees with it on each of those points. Bernstein polynomials are more appropriate in this case, as they uniformly converge to $f$.